# ошибка cudaSetDevice failed! Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed? CUDA 9.2 Visual studio 2015

Tags: c, visual-studio, cuda, nvidia

пытаюсь работать с CUDA 9.2 на видеокарте nvidia geforce gtx 950, используется по умолчанию при запуске VS.
Создаю стандартный проект NVIDIA, внутри генерируется код (см. ниже), запускаю, в итоге получаю следующее сообщение:

> cudaSetDevice failed!  Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed?
> addWithCuda failed!

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

cudaError_t addWithCuda(int *c, const int *a, const int *b, unsigned int size);

__global__ void addKernel(int *c, const int *a, const int *b)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}

int main()
{
    const int arraySize = 5;
    const int a[arraySize] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    const int b[arraySize] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
    int c[arraySize] = { 0 };

    // Add vectors in parallel.
    cudaError_t cudaStatus = addWithCuda(c, a, b, arraySize);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "addWithCuda failed!");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("{1,2,3,4,5} + {10,20,30,40,50} = {%d,%d,%d,%d,%d}\n",
        c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4]);

    // cudaDeviceReset must be called before exiting in order for profiling and
    // tracing tools such as Nsight and Visual Profiler to show complete traces.
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceReset();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceReset failed!");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

// Helper function for using CUDA to add vectors in parallel.
cudaError_t addWithCuda(int *c, const int *a, const int *b, unsigned int size)
{
    int *dev_a = 0;
    int *dev_b = 0;
    int *dev_c = 0;
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    // Choose which GPU to run on, change this on a multi-GPU system.
    cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSetDevice failed!  Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed?\n");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Allocate GPU buffers for three vectors (two input, one output)    .
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, size * sizeof(int));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!\n");
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, size * sizeof(int));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!\n");
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, size * sizeof(int));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!\n");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Copy input vectors from host memory to GPU buffers.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!\n");
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!\n");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Launch a kernel on the GPU with one thread for each element.
    addKernel<<<1, size>>>(dev_c, dev_a, dev_b);

    // Check for any errors launching the kernel
    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "addKernel launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
        goto Error;
    }
    
    // cudaDeviceSynchronize waits for the kernel to finish, and returns
    // any errors encountered during the launch.
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code %d after launching addKernel!\n", cudaStatus);
        goto Error;
    }

    // Copy output vector from GPU buffer to host memory.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!\n");
        goto Error;
    }

Error:
    cudaFree(dev_c);
    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_b);

    return cudaStatus;
}
```

При запуске через консоль (nvcc kernel.c -ccbin "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin") выдаёт следующее:

> kernel.c kernel.c(18): error C2057: требуется константное выражение
>
> kernel.c(18): error C2466: невозможно выделить память для массива постоянного нулевого размера kernel.c(19): error C2057: требуется
>
> константное выражение kernel.c(19): error C2466: невозможно выделить память для массива постоянного нулевого размера kernel.c(20): error
>
> C2057: требуется константное выражение
>
> kernel.c(20): error C2466: невозможно выделить память для массива постоянного нулевого размера
>
> kernel.c(91): error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: <

По уроку с ютуба пыталась запустить другой код, программа запускается, однако результат совсем не тот, что на видео - в переменной С лежит мусор вместо результата сложения 1 и 2.

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void kernel(int a, int b, int *c) {
    *c = a + b;
}

int main() {
    int c;
    int *dev_c;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, sizeof(int));
    kernel<<<1,1>>>(1, 2, dev_c);
    cudaMemcpy(&c, dev_c, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("%i\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

Кто-нибудь с таким сталкивался?

Comment: Вы проверяли что находится в результате выполнения `cudaSetDevice`?

Comment: Нет, но спасибо!) Нашла другую программу - там проверялись доступные оборудования, и в результате ни одно не было обнаружено. Только что переставила драйвер - работает корректно. Несколько часов потратила х))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Программа для проверки доступных девайсов [на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/54330/).

Помогло обновление драйвера.
Обновиться с помощью винды не удалось, пришлось с [официального сайта](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) качать и вручную обновлять. Geoforge expirience не работает, зато на вижуалке нормально распознаётся устройство.